# Why my words are divide on innerhtml line break?

Tags: angular

I get a html code from my databse with html tag.
I want to display it on my site, so i use : `[innerHTML]="selectedNews?.content | safe"`

If my content is : `Lorem ipsum is placeholder text`

At the end of a line, the word will be break rather than go to the next line.

Exemple :

```
Lorem ipsum is placehol
der text
```

Rather than

```
Lorem ipsum is 
placeholder text
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: That's non-standard behavior, so this would seem to indicate that there's styling applied causing the problem. We don't have enough information to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this attribute to the html element where this is added `[innerHTML]` :

`style='word-break: normal;'`

You then may want to try this as well:

`style='word-break: break-all;'`

if I understood correctly you are expecting `word-break: normal;`

```html
<style>
p {
  width: 170px; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

p.a {
  word-break: normal;
}

p.b {
  word-break: break-all;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>word-break: normal:</h3>
<p class="a">Lorem ipsum is 
placeholder text</p>

<h3>word-break: break-all:</h3>
<p class="b">Lorem ipsum is 
placeholder text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I did not know this property: D